# three.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I make a scene, where I want want to animate cube, but it keeps giving me a error : 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined

```
        function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();
        }

        function render() {

            var time = Date.now() * 0.005;
            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            for ( i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i ++ ) {
                var object = scene.children[ i ];
                if ( object instanceof THREE.PointCloud ) {
                    object.rotation.y += 0.01 ;
                    }
            }
            cube.rotation.y = time* 0.01;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
```

PoinCloud works perfectly, but for the cure it gives me an error.

Could anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: is `cube` a local or global variable?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. For whatever reason, `cube` has the value `undefined`. Since we can't see where `cube` has been initialised, you might want to look into what's happening with that.

Comment: it should be global. i first declared the variable, then in init function, created a 3d cube, after in render I try to rotate it, and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Could you please show us your init function? 
(maybe it's something like a declaration with var or on 'this')
you are sure init is ALWAYS called before render? (check Timeouts)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created cube like this?

`var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );`

Comment: yep! I created it in init function.

Comment: Try with some other browser to know any error message other than this and let me know

Comment: still, nothing. if I declare it as var cube = new THREE.Mesh( ); it doesn't show me any error, but doesn't animate also

Comment: THAT could be the problem. where do you have that line "var cube = THREE.Mesh();"? 
If you have this line within a function, the cube variable won't be in the global space. In this case, just remove the 'var'...

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, even getting the same code, that works (really, I went line by line checking them), I changed the line to:

```
for ( i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i ++ ) {

                var object = scene.children[ i ];

                if ( object instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                    object.rotation.y += 0.1 ;

                    }
            }
```

Comment: you first declare the objects, then in the render function you add code I posted above.